# Routing Member confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

So I have this:

```
resources :users do
    member do
        resources :items
    end
 end
```

so basically I want to have route like this - user/1/items,(only show all items that belonged to that specific user) which is achieved by that code above, my question is, I want also to show all items in general for the public. I tried adding resources :items below but they will use the same controller/action. anyone can give me ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this routes `users/1/items`, just do:

```
resources :users do
  resources :items
end
```

Above routes use `UsersController`.

Then below that route, use:

```
resources :items
```

About routes will use `ItemsController` and it matches routes: `/items`

Comment: what is the difference between using member do and not?

Comment: It's the same in your case, I just checked it again. With member it adds an id of model user.